# How to determine if 2 points are on opposite sides of a line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I determine whether the 2 points $(a_x, a_y)$ and $(b_x, b_y)$ are on opposite sides of the line $(x_1,y_1)\to(x_2,y_2)$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Explicitly, they are on opposite sides iff
$$((y_1-y_2)(a_x-x_1)+(x_2-x_1)(a_y-y_1))((y_1-y_2)(b_x-x_1)+(x_2-x_1)(b_y-y_1)) < 0.$$

Comment: Appreciate the explicitness of your answer. Clearly I am no math geek :) Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

Find the equation of the line. It should be of the form $ax + by + c = 0$. Given two points $(x_1, y_2)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, plug these into that equation. They are on opposite side of the line if $ax_1 + by_1 + c < 0$ and $ax_2 + by_2 + c > 0$, or visa-versa.

Answer (score 5):

$CD$ are on the opposite sides of $AB$ if and only if $\left(\overrightarrow{AB}\times\overrightarrow{AC}\right)\cdot\left(\overrightarrow{AB}\times\overrightarrow{AD}\right)<0$, where $\times$ is [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and $\cdot$ is [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: How is the cross product defined for 2 dimensions?

Comment: @martycohen Defined for an arbitrary embedding $\mathbb R^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: The cross product of two ℝ3 vectors is perpendicular to them. If both vectors are in ℝ2, the result is [0,0,z] and z could be negative, zero, or positive. Often the cross product of two ℝ2's is defined as just an ℝ1 value, x1y2-x2y1.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $A$ and $B$ for the points in question, and $P_1$ and $P_2$ for the points determining the line ...

Compute the "signed" areas of the $\triangle P_1 P_2 A$ and $\triangle P_1 P_2 B$ via the formula ([equation 16 here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html))
$$\frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1 
\end{array}\right|$$
with $(x_3,y_3)$ being $A$ or $B$. The points $A$ and $B$ will be on opposite sides of the line if the areas differ in sign, which indicates that the triangles are being traced-out in different directions (clockwise vs counterclockwise).

You can, of course, ignore the "$1/2$", as it has not affect the sign of the values. Be sure to keep the row-order consistent in the two computations, though.